# Dynamically access an excel worksheet

Tags: excel, dynamic, formula

I have an excel workbook where the sheets are named "1", "2", "3", etc.

I'd like to be able to access their contents dynamically, for instance, if I have a value on page "3" in cell A2 which equates to 2, I'd like to be able to do something like

```
=IF('(A2)'!L4 = "", 0.0, '(A2)'!L4)
```

in another cell on page "3" to access cell L4 on page "2".  Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at the [INDIRECT](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/indirect.htm) function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
=IF(INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!L4")="",0,INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!L4"))
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I wanted.  I had been looking at INDIRECT, but I just couldn't seem to get the syntax correct.